# Numerical analysis: error in taylor approx for twice differentiable function

Tags: numerical-methods

For an equation which is $\frac{f(x_{o}+h)-f(x_{o}-h)}{2h} = f'(x_{o})+\frac{h^{2}}{6}f'''(x_{o})$
 , the error term for $ f'(x_{o})$ is 
$\frac{h^{2}}{6}f'''(x_{o})$...

however, what happens if $f'''(x_{o})$ = 0 ? this means that f(x) is a twice differentiable function.

does it mean that the approximation error is none in this case for taylor approximation and we thus have exact value for $f'(x_{o})$ or would there be still be some form of error?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One should notice that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$ is an even function in $h$. Thus if the quadratic coefficient is zero, the next one is the one of degree 4 (provided the function is in $C^5$). There exist rare cases where the error term is exactly zero, but in general one can not count on that.